# PHCollection: Fetch all albums, sorted by most-recently edited

Tags: ios, photosframework

In Apple’s `Photos` framework, there’s a class `PHAssetCollection`, which represents the Albums in a user’s library.

I’d like to fetch the albums and sort them by the date they were last edited (as in, the date that a photo was last added-to or removed-from the album) - and I’ve yet to find a way to do this.

Is there a way to write a query that returns albums sorted by most-recently-edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a query that returns albums sorted by most-recently-edited?

No. A PHAssetCollection doesn't have any property telling you its modified date, and a PHAsset doesn't have any property telling you when it was added to a collection.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that was my hypothesis, too. Wish it existed!

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `PHAssetCollection.endDate` say:

> This property applies only to asset collections whose type is PHAssetCollectionType.moment. For other asset collection types, this property’s value is nil.

But in my experience this is false and endDate will tell you the date of the most recent photo in the collection. So if you have a list of albums:

```
albums.sort { (a1, a2) -> Bool in
    if let d1 = a1.endDate, let d2 = a2.endDate {
        return d1 > d2
    } else {
        return true // aka kind of random
    }
}
```